# During input check for duplicates and if one is found merge duplicate info into the three columns of the input line of webgrid using C#

Tags: c#, merge

I've never seen this done in C# before, and am really hoping that someone can come up with an answer to this question. In the trailerNumber column all trailer numbers are unique, but if a person inputs into that column, the program will check for a duplicate entry upon input and identify that it is a duplicate, give a messagebox asking "what do you want to do, merge the old entry into the input with the three columns of info or do nothing.

Columns:

```
LocationID Section TrailerNumber CarrierName LoadCommodityStatus DateLoaded PlantLocation Actions
1   D001    EASTD51                                              2000-01-01 102 - Fort Worth, TX    Edit Clear
2   D001    SOUTHD                                               2000-01-01 116 - Las Vegas, NV Edit Clear
3   D001    DOCK                                                 2000-01-01 109 - Quincy, IL    Edit Clear
4   D001    SOUTHD     123PPP                                    2000-01-01 110 - Riverside, MO Edit Clear
5   D002    EASTD51                                              2000-01-01 102 - Fort Worth, TX    Edit Clear
6   D002    SOUTHD                                               2000-01-01 116 - Las Vegas, NV Edit Clear
7   D002    DOCK                                                 2000-01-01 109 - Quincy, IL    Edit Clear
8   D002    SOUTHD                                               2000-01-01 110 - Riverside, MO Edit Clear
9   D003    EASTD51                                              2000-01-01 102 - Fort Worth, TX    Edit Clear
10  D003    SOUTHD                                               2000-01-01 116 - Las Vegas, NV Edit Clear
11  D003    DOCK    123PPP  BRANON  CHEP                         2019-10-28 109 - Quincy, IL    Edit Clear
12  D003    SOUTHD                                               2019-06-25 110 - Riverside, MO Edit Clear
13  D004    EASTD51                                              2000-01-01 102 - Fort Worth, TX    Edit Clear
14  D004    NORTHD  AAA111                                       2019-10-02 116 - Las Vegas, NV Edit Clear
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is merge where the duplicate info is found on the three adjacent columar information (TrailerNumber, CarrierName, LoadCommodityStatus) to the input row, then make the old row TrailerNumber, CarrierName, LoadCommodityStatus all null.

Upon input duplicate entry is found in TrailerNumber column, takes the information in the CarrierName, LoadCommodityStatus of the old row and places it into the input row while making the TrailerNumber, CarrierName, LoadCommodityStatus null of where the duplicate was found in the old row.

Here is my code:
Index:

```
@model YardDog.Model.YardDogModel
  @{
Layout = null;
ViewBag.Title = "Yard Dog";
WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.LocationDatas, canPage: true, canSort: true, 
   sortDirectionFieldName: "Section", rowsPerPage: 50);

 }

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <head>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Yard Dog</title>

    <link href="~/Content/YardDogStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YardDogStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="time"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s; //Get the time.
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Date: " + today; //Get the Date.
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
</SCRIPT>

<div>
    <form id="formYardDog" class="formYardDog" runat="server" method="post">

        <asp:Panel id="Panel2" runat="server" ID="Panel2" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <h2 id="YardDog_DogText">Yard Dog (Tractor/Truck Locator)</h2>
            <img src="~/img/BullDogSmall.png" />


        </asp:Panel>

        <hr />
       
            <!--Location of Tutorial for DropDownList functionality using MVC:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-Data-using-DropDownList-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx -->

            @{ int firstRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 1;
                int lastRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 
      webGrid.Rows.Count();
            }
        <div><b id="RowCount">Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>

        <div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "formYardDog" }))
                    {   
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Section, Model.Section, "Section", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlSection", @class = "ddlSection" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlantLocation, Model.PlantLocation, "PlantLocation", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlWarehouses", @class = "ddlWarehouses" })
                    }
            <hr />

            @webGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
             htmlAttributes: new { @id = "webGrid" },
             columns: webGrid.Columns(
        webGrid.Column(header: "LocationID", format: @<span class="label">@item.LocationID</span>, style: "LocationID"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "Location", format: @<span class="label">@item.Location</span>, style: "Location"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "Section", format: @<span class="label">@item.Section</span>, style: "Section"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "TrailerNumber", format: @<span>
            <span class="label">@item.TrailerNumber</span>
            <input id="TrailerNumber" class="text" type="text" value="@item.TrailerNumber" style="display:none" />
        </span>, style: "TrailerNumber"),

         webGrid.Column(header: "CarrierName", format: @<span>
            <span class="label">@item.CarrierName</span>
            <input id="CarrierName" class="text" type="text" value="@item.CarrierName" style="display:none" />
        </span>, style: "CarrierName"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "LoadCommodityStatus", format: @<span>
            <span class="label">@item.LoadCommodityStatus</span>
            <input id="LoadCommodityStatus" class="text" type="text" value="@item.LoadCommodityStatus" style="display:none" />
        </span>, style: "LoadCommodityStatus"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "DateLoaded", format: @<span class="label">@item.DateLoaded</span>, style: "DateLoaded"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "PlantLocation", format: @<span class="label">@item.PlantLocation</span>, style: "PlantLocation"),

        webGrid.Column(header: "Actions", format:@<span class="link">
            <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
            <a class="Clear" href="javascript:;">Clear</a>
            <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
            <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>


        </span>)))

            <div><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>

        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="WebGridTable">

        </div>
   </form>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //DropDownList PlantLocation handler.
    $("body").on("change", "#ddlPlantLocation", function () {

        $('#formYardDog')[0].submit();
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid tfoot a", function () {
        $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
        return false;
    });

    //DropDownList Section handler.
    $("body").on("change", "#ddlSection", function () {

        $('#formYardDog')[0].submit();
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid tfoot a", function () {
        $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
        return false;
    });

    //Highlight Duplicates.
    $(function () {
        //HighLightDuplicate('GridviewN');
        HighLightDuplicate('#webGrid ');
    });

    function HighLightDuplicate(WebGrid) {
        var inputs = $('[id*=' + WebGrid + '] tr').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').find('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                if (inputs[i] != inputs[j]
                    && (inputs[i].value != "" || inputs[j].value != "")
                    && inputs[i].value == inputs[j].value) {
                    inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    inputs[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    inputs[i].parentNode.bgColor = "red";
                    inputs[j].parentNode.bgColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Edit event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Edit", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                $(this).find(".text").show();
                $(this).find(".label").hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Clear").hide();
        row.find(".Update").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //Clear event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Clear", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                $(this).find(".text").show();
                $(this).find(".label").hide();
                span.html(input.val(null));
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Cancel").show();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        $(this).hide();
        var clear = {};
        clear.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
        clear.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
        clear.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
        clear.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
        clear.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
        clear.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
        clear.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
        clear.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ClearCustomer",
            data: '{clear:' + JSON.stringify(clear) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }); setInterval('location.reload()', 500);
    });

    //Update event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid  TBODY .Update", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                span.html(input.val());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").hide();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        $(this).hide();
        var customer = {};
        customer.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
        customer.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
        customer.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
        customer.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
        customer.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
        customer.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
        customer.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
        customer.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
            data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }); setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
    });

    //Duplicate finder event handler.
    $(function () {
        HighLightDuplicate('#webGrid');
        //HighLightDuplicate('GridviewC');
    });

    function HighLightDuplicate(webGrid) {
        var inputs = $('[id*= #TrailerNumber' + webGrid + '] tr').not(':first-child').not(':last-child').find('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                if (inputs[i] != inputs[j]
                    && (inputs[i].value != "" || inputs[j].value != "")
                    && inputs[i].value == inputs[j].value) {
                    inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    inputs[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    inputs[i].parentNode.bgColor = "red";
                    inputs[j].parentNode.bgColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //Cancel event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Cancel", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                input.val(span.html());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        row.find(".Update").hide();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //Submit the Form to the URL.
        $(function () {
            $('th a, tfoot a').click(function () {
                $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
                return false;
            });
});
</script>
```

HomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ClassLibraryDAL.DAL;
using YardDog.Model;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;

namespace YardDog.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //public object inputPageRows { get; private set; }
    //public int InputPageRows { get; private set; }


    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        YardDogModel model = PopulateModel(null, null);

        return View(model);
    }
    //Controls DropDownList PlantLocation/Section Selection.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string plantLocation, string section)
    {
        YardDogModel model = PopulateModel(plantLocation, section);
        return View(model);
    }
    /*
    public ActionResult Index(int inputPageRows)
    {
      
        InputPageRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return View(inputPageRows);
    }
    */
    //Population Controller. 
    private static YardDogModel PopulateModel(string plantLocation, string section)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntities entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntities())
        {
            YardDogModel model = new YardDogModel()
            {
                LocationDatas = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where c.PlantLocation == plantLocation && c.Section == section && c.Section == section && c.PlantLocation == plantLocation || string.IsNullOrEmpty(plantLocation) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(section) && c.PlantLocation == plantLocation //&& c.Section == city || string.IsNullOrEmpty(city)
                                 select c).ToList(),

                Section = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && plantLocation == c.PlantLocation
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),

                PlantLocation = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where (c.PlantLocation == c.PlantLocation)
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = c.PlantLocation, Value = c.PlantLocation }).Distinct().ToList()
            };
            return model;
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(LocationData customer)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntities entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntities())
        {
            LocationData updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                            where c.LocationID == customer.LocationID
                                            select c).FirstOrDefault();
            //Check for Duplicates.
            FindDuplicates(customer);

            //x => customer.TrailerNumber == x.TrailerNumber && x.TrailerNumber == customer.TrailerNumber //errases all data except the first cell TrailerNumber.
            if (customer.TrailerNumber != null) updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = customer.TrailerNumber.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = customer.TrailerNumber = null;

            if (customer.CarrierName != null) updatedCustomer.CarrierName = customer.CarrierName.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.CarrierName = customer.CarrierName = null;

            if (customer.LoadCommodityStatus != null) updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = customer.LoadCommodityStatus.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = customer.LoadCommodityStatus = null;

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClearCustomer(LocationData clear)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntities entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntities())
        {
            LocationData updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                            where c.LocationID == clear.LocationID
                                            select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (clear.TrailerNumber != null) updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = null;
            else updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = clear.TrailerNumber = null;

            if (clear.CarrierName != null) updatedCustomer.CarrierName = null;
            else updatedCustomer.CarrierName = clear.CarrierName = null;

            if (clear.LoadCommodityStatus != null) updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = null;
            else updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = clear.LoadCommodityStatus = null;

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    //Alert for Duplicate TrailerNumber. 
    private string FindDuplicates(LocationData customer)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntities entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntities())
        {

            var query = customer.TrailerNumber.GroupBy(x => x)
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .Select(y => y.Key)
          .ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            //while (customer.TrailerNumber.Count() > 1 || DialogResult.No.Equals(true) && customer.TrailerNumber.Count() == 1)
            {
                //process
                string Duplicate = customer.TrailerNumber;
                if (MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Trailer Number Found! Keep Entry?", Duplicate, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    customer.TrailerNumber = customer.TrailerNumber;
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do Nothing.
                   // customer.TrailerNumber = null;
                    //entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return customer.TrailerNumber;
        }



    }
    
    //Change the number of rows on the form.
    /*
    public int ChangeNumberRows(int inputRows)
    {
        
        inputPageRows = inputRows;
        InputPageRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        return InputPageRows;
    }
    */
}

}
```

Model:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using ClassLibraryDAL.DAL;

 namespace YardDog.Model
{
public class YardDogModel
{
    
    public List<LocationData> LocationDatas { get; set; }
    public List<LocationData> LocationDatasSection { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PlantLocation { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Section { get; set; }
    
}
}
```

[image: Input Columns]

[image: Result of input]

Note: Make old columns null in row of TrailerNumber, CarrierName, LoadCommodityStatus.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Make Message box asking if you would like to merge, Yes/No then make input row the same as duplicate row and then make old duplicate row null in all three fields. For instance LocationID 4 would be copied from LocationID 11  to show 123PPP BANON CHEP on LocationID 4 row and then make LocationID 11 null in all three fields. So it would be moving the data to the input row, update the row in the webgrid/database.